# Customizing iOS Navigation Bar height, add background, menu button (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uinavigationbar

I've started developing in iOS last week and I've been trying to accomplish the following design to the Nav bar of my iOS app. So far, all I can do is change the background and add an image in the center. How do I resize the height of the navigation bar, add background and the buttons?

[image]

Comment: you can not change height of native navigation bar if you want then you can use custom view as navigation bar and can do all required things

Comment: I think this may help [Customizing UINavigationbar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: This question is too broad, you don't show an issue, you ask to make a full project. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this in a storyboard, or adding constraints via code.

**Place a toolbar on top with these constraints:**

1. Top Space to Superview = 0
2. Leading Space to Superview = 0
3. Trailing Space to Superview = 0
4. Height Equals = 80 (or whatever value you want)

**Place navigation bar below the toolbar with these constraints:**

1. List item
2. Top Space to the Toolbar = 0
3. Leading Space to Superview = 0
4. Trailing Space to Superview = 0
5. Height Equals = 64 (or whatever value you want)

**Add items to you Toolbar starting from the left:**

1. Add a Bar Button Item for the Menu Button
2. Add a Flexible Space Bar Button Item
3. Add a Bar Button Item for the Owl Button Image
4. Add a Flexible Space Bar Button Item

**Add items to your Navigation Bar:**

1. Add a Bar Button Item for the Back Button

---

## Storyboard Example

[image: Example Image]

Comment: The layout worked for me! :D May I know if it's possible to add a background like in the picture?

Comment: how do I implement this in a tableview controller?

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe Apple allows you to change the height of the navigation bar. However, certain visual attributes can be altered, such as background image.

Refer to this document:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006887-CH3-SW16